# How to stop Varnish from caching Sitemap?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, sitemap, varnish

I'm running a Wordpress blog on Nginx and Varnish. I'm using the following configuration for Varnish:

```
# This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
# 
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
# 
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
    .max_connections = 800;
}


acl purge {
        "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.grace = 2m;

  # Set X-Forwarded-For header for logging in nginx
  remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
  set    req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;


  # Remove has_js and CloudFlare/Google Analytics __* cookies.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
  # Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");



# Either the admin pages or the login
if (req.url ~ "/wp-(login|admin|cron)") {
        # Don't cache, pass to backend
        return (pass);
}


# Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Remove the wp test cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Static content unique to the theme can be cached (so no user uploaded images)
# The reason I don't take the wp-content/uploads is because of cache size on bigger blogs
# that would fill up with all those files getting pushed into cache
if (req.url ~ "wp-content/themes/" && req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e)?g)") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
}

# Even if no cookies are present, I don't want my "uploads" to be cached due to their potential size
if (req.url ~ "/wp-content/uploads/") {
    return (pass);
}

# Check the cookies for wordpress-specific items
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_" || req.http.Cookie ~ "comment_") {
        # A wordpress specific cookie has been set
    return (pass);
}



    # allow PURGE from localhost
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            error 405 "Not allowed.";
        }
        return (lookup);
    }


    # Force lookup if the request is a no-cache request from the client
    if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
        return (pass);
    }


# Try a cache-lookup
return (lookup);

}

sub vcl_fetch {
    #set obj.grace = 5m;
    set beresp.grace = 2m;

}

sub vcl_hit {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                purge;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}

sub vcl_miss {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                purge;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}
```

I've followed the tutorial [mentioned here](http://theartofcode.tv/installing-wordpress-on-ec2/)

Everything works fine, but I'm using [Yoast SEO Plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/) to generate the Sitemap dynamically after every new post. It generates a sitemap index named `sitemap_index.xml` that contains other sitemaps (for posts, pages, author etc). This is also working fine.

1. The problem is how can I prevent Varnish from caching my Sitemaps?
2. How can I prevent Varnish from messing with Google Analytics? It shouldn't stop GA from providing me with a correct report.

I'm new to Varnish, can someone please guide me on how to modify the config. :( Please help.

**UPDATE:**

Will it work if I include the following into `sub vcl_recv`

```
if (req.url ~ "\.xml(\.gz)?$") {
   return (pass);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried your example for sitemap? It should work. You should put it above return (lookup);

Comment: I've updated the file. We're yet to post any news now. I'll have to wait and monitor it's changes. Btw, is the configuration correct for Google Analytics? Will it have any bad effect on GA? Do I need to change anything?

Comment: No you will not have any impact on GA. GA is executed on client site (it is javascript). When you unset cookies in Varnish config - your WordPress site will not see them, but browser and GA will. You can check in FireBug that all cookies like wp-settings-1 are ok, but if you will try to get this cookies from PHP side you will not see them. Varnish will unset them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PLEASE** remove these lines !!

```
if (req.url ~ "\.xml(\.gz)?$") {
   return (pass);
}
```

*Returning (pass)* is a workaround but it's not how you want to use Varnish.
Varnish is here to cache pages and contents like `sitemap_index.xml`

You already implemented PURGE mechanism in VCL, so the simplest way to handle your `sitemap_index.xml` issue is to PURGE it !

The basic principle is that `sitemap_index.xml` need to be cached as long as no new post has been made. Then, every time a new post is created, you have to inform Varnish that `sitemap_index.xml` is no longer valid by sending the HTTP request below (pasted from official documentation (1)) :

```
PURGE /sitemap_index.xml HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com
```

So, I guess you will have the choice by editing your module manually or by using the Varnish HTTP Purge / WordPress module (and probably hack it manually also) (2)

1. https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/purging.html#http-purges
2. http://wordpress.org/plugins/varnish-http-purge/

Answer (score 1):

> Will it work if I include the following into sub vcl_recv
>
> if (req.url ~ ".xml(.gz)?$") {
>         return (pass);
>      }

This will work. Place it near the top of the function. Keep in mind though, that it will prevent caching of **all** .xml files and **all** .xml.gz files. Granted, most of the xml files and xml.gz files you are probably serving, site maps, still it is a consideration, in case they are not.

Answer (score 0):

i can`t give you the exact syntax, but you should pipe* the request for the sitemap.

*pipe - match the request in your vcl and direct it always to fetch it from the server.

Comment: Pipe is not a good idea https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/vcl.html. Pipe is used for streaming. If you want to get file not from cache you should use return(pass).